# SELECT all COLUMN_NAMES from a table that have a specific entry

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 21 columns and I need to find all column names that have a specific value in them. This goes beyond my knowledge of database querying.

If this is possible, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to find columns in which the name of the column contains a certain value or there exists a row in which the given column contains the given value?

In the first case you could try the show columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a specific column value to query on. The only thing I have is a value that could be inside that column. Something like: "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM 'table' WHERE <any column> = 'value'". So I think I mean the second one.

Comment: Is this a one-time job? In that case i would go with 21 queries, joining and deduplicating them in whatever works and not bother getting it any cleaner.

Comment: Yes, this is a one-time job. So I would end up with something like: "SELECT column_1 FROM table WHERE column_1 LIKE 'value'. x 21. It's what I had in mind, it's ugly but if there's no other way I will have to live with it :-)